# getting machine data under Linux system

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, glib

How can i get the following data using c/c++ using gtk+, glib.

machine serial, CPU serial, machine MAC address and other machine information.

Regards,
Lenin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SIOCGIFADDR 
check out the code given in this link.
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/linux-determining-mac-address-from-c-38217/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you call lshw from your c-code and parse the result?

Comment: That would require lshw being installed, and may not be allowed (think of selinux, apparmor,..) on the machine.

Comment: True, then maybe take the sources of lshw and take the parts you are interested in.